# Facebook Graph API - Get a facebook user's birthday (without requiring the user to allow permission)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get a user's birthday (without requiring the user to allow explicit Permissions)?

I am using the Graph API to get the user's information like the link: https://graph.facebook.com/mhiella.vexiia (Note: Deprecated API) But I don't see the user's birthday.

Comment: The latest API does include an Age Range on the public API that will give you 13-17, 18-20 and 21+ which may be of use.

Answer (score 6):

You can't get a user's birthday without an [Extended Profile Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/) of **user_birthday**. This means that you **MUST** have an Access Token with a user_birthday permission in order to access any user's birthday.

Without an access token, you can only retrieve [Public Profile Data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/) for a particular user.